# origin of "Liar, liar, Pants on fire"

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

In the etymology age where every possible expression seems to have been run down to its true source, 'Liar, liar, Pants on fire' stands apart because I just googled it and nobody knows its origin fo' sure!

> [Google search for "liar liar pants on fire" origin](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22liar+liar+pants+on+fire%22+origin&oq=%22liar+liar+pants+on+fire%22+origin&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

It is usually attributed (inconclusively and without much evidence, as far as I can make out) to an over-200-year-old poem apparently by William Blake, which is itself suspected of being a fake. Can some etymology wizard at ELU provide an authoritative answer backed by appropriate citation?

Peculiar usage: an old person in my hometown, who loved American colloquialisms, used to twist this around and say, "if it looks like pants and it seems to be on fire, then it's probably a liar!" [He later left India to join his son in the USA.]

Comment: I was suspecting that there was a tie between lying and fire prior to the expression. I don't really know the bible well.. I know bugs bunny has the devil on fire.  I barely skimmed Dante's inferno in college.. I googled "dante's inferno lying" and stumbled to this section : Bolgia Eight: In this trench, the souls of Deceivers who gave false or corrupted advice to others for personal benefit are punished. They are constantly ablaze, appearing as nothing so much as living, speaking tongues of flame.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malebolge

Comment: If lying were commonly tied to "catching fire" I could see a doggerel being made up.. why pants?

Comment: Must be something about liar-crying "*Fire!*" in a crowded theater. Came into use after the existence of crowded theaters... ;-)

Comment: There can be no serious doubt that the poem is nothing but a poor parody. "When you asked to borrow my stallion/ To visit a nearby-moored galleon/ How could I ever know that you/ Intended only to turn him into Glue?"

Comment: The following source offers an interesting insight into its possible origin: http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/liar_liar_pants_on_fire

Comment: @Tom22 I don'[t know about things catching fire, but the idea of testing accused liars with an ordeal by fire was once well rooted. Perhaps school kids made up the rhyme after learning about that.

Comment: Intriguing suggestions from one and all. Thanks a lot for the interest! NOW IF somebody would write a well-referenced answer in the classical ELU style.... I know this is a difficult question because it is not so easy to pinpoint the origin of schoolyard chants and other colloquial expressions.

Comment: @Mari-lou A I have edited the question to include the useful link to the more specific google search ("liar liar pants on fire" origin) you suggested.

Comment: The poem itself sounds crude and unpoetic, so it seems like somebody has been 'hanging it' on the great poet who surely would have written finer verses? “Deceiver, dissembler Your trousers are alight // From what pole or gallows Shall they dangle in the night” sounds especially threatening; *OMG! I an quaking in my boots...*

Comment: The exact expression (or taunt) "Liar, liar, pants on fire" was certainly known across schoolyards in the United States by the early 1960s. It provided the inspiration for the Castaways' 1965 hit single "[Liar Liar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8rCy173y7Y)," but goes back before that to my earliest memories of childhood philosophical investigations (near the beginning of the 1960s). Prior to the Castaways' hit, however, I had not heard the Pinocchio-inspired followup insult "Your nose is longer than a telephone wire.")

Comment: @Sven Yargs thank you for sharing your experience; the origins of such phrases are fascinating if rather 'obscured by the mists of time.' The reason I heard it recently is that a short, fat child named Kitty (age 6) shouted *"liar, liar, pants on fire!"* when her 4 year old brother made a tall claim about the length of snakes. Interestingly enough, the Cambridge English dictionary online defines 'tall claim' as [Indian English for 'tall story'](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tall-claim) which was news to me and shows just how much our geography influences our English!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the phrase "*Liar! Liar!*" seems to be older than the popular phrase associated with burning trousers.  OED provides an early citation of the phrase used twice in a row:

> **a1607**   H. Chettle Trag. Hoffman (1631) sig. I2v   **Lyer, lyer, licke dish**.

I was able to locate the full verse in a later edition of the same book.

[image]

- [Henry Chettle · The tragedy of Hoffman; or, A reuenge for a father](https://books.google.com/books?id=LhwtAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA60&dq=Henry%20Chettle%20%C2%B7%20The%20tragedy%20of%20Hoffman%20%22lyer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNqe2VndLUAhVIcj4KHT2BBd8Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=Henry%20Chettle%20%C2%B7%20The%20tragedy%20of%20Hoffman%20%22lyer%22&f=false)

The phrase "licke dish," is interesting and personally I don't know how to explain that turn of phrase.  However, it is remarkably similar to the phrase "lick spit" seen later in a context that seems relevant to *pants on fire*:

> [image]

- [Percy Society - Volume 4 - Page 135 (Early English Poetry, Ballads, and popular literature of the Middle Ages)](https://books.google.com/books?id=TdNNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA135&dq=Liar,%20liar,%20lick%20spit;%20Turn%20about%20the%20candlestick.%20What%E2%80%99s%20good%20for%20liar?%20Brimstone%20and%20fire.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK2qjLodLUAhWESiYKHRLiCX4Q6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=Liar%2C%20liar%2C%20lick%20spit%3B%20Turn%20about%20the%20candlestick.%20What%E2%80%99s%20good%20for%20liar%3F%20Brimstone%20and%20fire.&f=false) (**1841**)

---

Meanwhile, use of "*Liar! liar!*" repeated for emphasis appears reasonably common in the 1800's.  A few examples:

> 'I know nothing of acoustics, Signor.  I am at a loss to understand your meaning," said he softly.
>
> **'Liar! liar!'** shouted I.

- **1852** - [Cooper's Clarksburg Register (Clarksburg, West Virginia)17 Mar 1852, Wed](https://www.newspapers.com/image/171932191/?terms=%22liar%2Bliar%22) (paywall)

> But his chosen organs, the Tribune, and other black Republican papers, and the black Republican preachers, have unceasingly denied it, with vulgar epithets of lie! lie! and **liar! liar!**

- **1856** - [Fayetteville Weekly Observer (Fayetteville, North Carolina)20 Oct 1856, Mon](https://www.newspapers.com/image/63391558/?terms=%22liar%2Bliar%22) (payewall)

> **'Liar, liar!'** shouted the woman, springing forward to clutch the jewel

- **1859** - [Republican Democrat (Ravenna, Ohio)13 Apr 1859, Wed](https://www.newspapers.com/image/143797111/?terms=%22liar%2Bliar%22) (paywall)

---

[The article](http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/liar_liar_pants_on_fire) cited by Josh in the comments claims that the full line ("Liar, liar, pants on fire") was cited in print in 1933.  The earliest reference I could find was from 1945, but clearly alludes at a historical context around the phrase:

> "**Liar liar pants on fire, Nose as long as a telephone wire!**" sang Fenella to the timeless scornful tune of childhood. "Anyway I'm not black," said Christine. "Anyway I'm not white," said Fenella. "So!"

[image]

- [Harper's Bazaar, 1945](https://books.google.com/books?id=8t0hAQAAMAAJ&q=liar%20liar%20pants&dq=liar%20liar%20pants&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAz_eWpNLUAhVEaD4KHZQ-B7IQ6AEILjAB)

---

Overall, this collection of references still seems to suggest that the phrase, in some form or another, was used in verse before any sources I've been able to locate.

---

While I have no direct evidence of a link, the rhyming line "nose as long as a telephone wire" suggests a possible allusion to the popular and widely translated children's novel [*The Adventures of Pinocchio*](http://fathom.lib.uchicago.edu/2/72810000/72810000_pinocchio.pdf) (**1881-1883**) by Carlo Collodi, where, as most readers probably know, the marionette Pinocchio's nose grew each time he told lies.

Following this line of speculation, it seems worth noting that at three points in the novel, Pinocchio is threatened with burning as firewood.

> He swam on and on. After a while, he turned around again
>   and called louder than before:
>
> "Good-by, Master. If you ever need a piece of good dry firewood,
>   remember me."

Comment: I seem to have read through several of the same sites, one of which explained the 'lock dish' as being a reference to dogs liking at their dishes to pretend they haven't been fed. I didn't keep the link unfortunately.

Comment: @Spagirl that makes sense, and could explain why "lick dish" and "lick spit" appear to mean the same thing (maybe?)

Comment: Thanks for another fine answer from RaceYouAnytime -- I upvote! You have marshalled strong evidence that the current phrase probably didn't have a single point of origin, but evolved through linked variant usages.

Comment: See also: ***Pants on fire !*** https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/dictionary/pants-on-fire/

Comment: @Josh in the context of that 'pants on fire' rating I wonder if 'politifact' itself will enter the English language as an euphemism, as in *is that a fact or a politifact?*

Comment: @EnglishStudent Well, it's one syllable shorter than _alternative fact_. ;-)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Very true. Moreover it seems intuitive that 'politi'facts should be treated with caution, and it has a *nice ring to it.*

Comment: You are most welcome @RaceYouAnytime! I was re-reading the answers to all my questions with a view to awarding a bounty for 2 of the best answers so far. I recently completed 7 months on ELU and Stack Exchange and wanted to cross 5000 rep simultaneously on ELU and Interpersonal.SE; hence I decided to award 2 bounties here on ELU to the most deserving answers (to allow time for my IPS.SE score to catch up with ELU) **and your answer was one of the best.**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "liar, liar pants on fire" was inspired from Revelations 21:8: "But the cowardly, the unbelieving, the vile, the murderers, the sexually immoral, those who practice magic arts, the idolaters and all liars—they will be consigned to the fiery lake of burning sulfur. This is the second death."

Answer (score 0):

In The Ramayana, written in India around 200-300 BCE, the monkey ally of Rama known as Hanuman has his tail lit on fire by Ravana for supposedly lying. This backfires on Ravana and sets the entire city of Lanka on fire in the process. This would be a more likely source of origin than a disambiguation from Revelations, though its possible both sources share a common ancestor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think people are just looking a bit too hard. It’s been around for a while, but I doubt it’s biblical or anything. The words rhyme, and it’s likely that simple. Even old poems that might it seem based on contain the rhyme for he same reason.

I seem to recall an additional line, “... hanging up on the telephone wire!” After the initial chant.

Answer (score -1):

Have never heard that second line and finally at 73 I decided I'd best learn the rest of the poem - certainly nondescript 
- maybe I shall complete the lyrics. 
© 
*"Liar liar pants on fire 
Matches caught you out you liar
Tell the truth and you will see, 
Happier you'll always be."